# Trying to prove that the set of global minimisers of a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex set

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, convex-analysis

> Prove that the set of global minimisers of a convex function
> $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ over the convex set $\Omega$ is
> a convex set

I have been told to consider the set $$S=\{\underline{x}\in\Omega : f(\underline{x})\leq \gamma\},$$ where $\gamma$ is value of $f$ at the minimising points. Let both $\underline{x},\underline{y}\in S$ and $\theta\in [0,1]$ be arbitrary, such that $f(\underline{x})\leq\gamma$ and $f(\underline{y})\leq\gamma \hspace{8pt} (1)$.  Then
\begin{align*}
f(\theta\underline{x}+(1-\theta)\underline{y})&\leq\theta f(\underline{x})+(1-\theta)f(\underline{y}) \hspace{20pt}\text{($f$ is convex)} \\
&=\theta\gamma+(1-\theta)\gamma \hspace{47pt}\text{(by $(1)$)}\\
&=\gamma
\end{align*}
Hence $\theta\underline{x}+(1-\theta)\underline{y}\in S \ \ \forall \underline{x},\underline{y}\in\Omega$ and $\theta\in [0,1]$.

Though I don't fully understand how the set $S$ represents the set of global minimizers of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma$ is the infimum of the function then $\gamma \leq f(x)$ is satisfied for any $x$. So $x \in S$ iff $f(x)=\gamma$ which menns $f$ is minimized at $x$.

Comment: So my set should be instead $S=\{\underline{x}\in\Omega : \gamma\leq f(\underline{x})\}$?

Comment: No, that set is all of $\Omega$. $S=\{x: f(x) \leq \gamma\}$ is precisely the set of points $x$ where $f(x)$ is equal to $\gamma$ which means it is the set of points where the minimum is attained.  @MB

Comment: By definition, a point $x^*\in\Omega$ is a global minimiser of $f(x)$ over $\Omega$ if and only if $f(x^*)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in\Omega$. In this case, does $\gamma=f(x^*)$?

Comment: @MB Yes. $x^{*}$ is a global minimizer iff $f(x^{*})=\gamma$ since $\gamma$ is defined as $\inf \{f(x): x \in \Omega\}$.

Comment: So if $f(x^*)=\gamma$, then by the definition $\gamma\leq f(x)\iff f(x)\geq\gamma$. Why is this not correct?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^{2}$ on the real line so that the infimum  $\gamma =0$. See what $S$ is .You  are getting unnecessarily confused and the best way to get the doubts cleared is to take an exmaple. Is the set of minimizers in thes case equal to what is stated in the problem or is it what you are proposing? @MB

Comment: You are saying that the inequality should be $f(x)\leq\gamma$ for all $x\in\Omega$. Consider the function $f(x)=x^2$ defined on $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$. Then $\gamma=0$, which I agree with. Now consider the point $x=1\in\mathbb{R}\implies f(x)=1$. Clearly $f(x)=1\geq \gamma=0$, so what am I missing here?

Comment: It is precisely true, my point exactly. That is $f(x)\geq \gamma$. But you are saying $f(x)\leq\gamma$?